# Android : how to NOT bring the app to front when the user clicks on a button in the notification?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, push-notification, notifications

I have got a notification with buttons on it and these buttons modify the notification interface when the user clicks on one of them.

The notification interface updates properly but...the main activity of my app is also brought to front.

How to avoid bringing the app to front?

Thanks !!!

Comment: could you share some code?

Comment: How are you getting the notification ? Is it Firebase or are you self generating ? It would be much clear if you share some code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Found the solution ! The intent of the notification has to fire a service and not an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution !

The intent of the notification has to fire a service and not an activity.

```
Intent buttonsIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationManagementService.class);
        buttonsIntent.putExtra("do_action", action);
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notifButton, PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, buttonsIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        notification.contentView = contentView;
  mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```